# How do I iterate over an integer that has string values in python

Tags: python

I have a list of film titles and time from my class attributes. I have displayed this list with:

```
for i in range(0, len(films)):
     print(i, films[i].title, films[i].time)
```

This gives me a list of the titles in number and time.

Now I want to get at any item in title so that I could make calculation on based on the choice with number of seats.

I tried this:

```
i = int(input("Please select from our listings :"))
while i <= films[i].title:
    i = input("Please select from our listings :")
    if i in films[i].title:
        print("You have selected film: ",films[i].title)
        print("Regular seat: ", choice[regular], "\nVip Seat: ", choice[vip], "\nDiamond Seat: ", choice[diamond], "\nPlatinum Seat: ", choice[platinum], "\nDisability Regular Seat: ", disabilityRegular, "\nDisability Vip Seat: ", disabilityVip, "\nDisability Diamond Seat", disabilityDiamond, "\nDisability Platinum Seat", disabilityPlatinum )
        seatType = input("\nSelect your seat from these list: ")
        seating = int(input("How many seats: "))

        if seating == items in choice:
            total = seating*altogether[seatType]
            print(total)
```

when run it displays this:(Note the list starts from 0):

```
29 End of Watch 20:00
30 Gremlins 19:30
31 The Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn part 2 20:00

Please select from our listings :6
Please select from our listings :4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/cin.py", line 91, in <module>
    if i in films[i].title:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

Comment: "if i in films[i].title" is the problem. I'm not sure what you're actually trying to achieve, but it's trying to use an integer (i) in a comparison with a string (films[i].title).

Comment: also, check the difference between the first and third line.(int)

Comment: @Talvalin, what I am trying to achieve is if the user selects say a film in position 9, I want to access that position independently and not as a list in other to make a calculation.

Answer (score 1):

```
if i in films[i].title:
```

tries to match an integer within a string. You have to convert the integer into a string first:

```
if str(i) in films[i].title:
```

But this will match `2` to names like `'... part 2'`, but also `'1492: Conquest of Paradise'`.

If you want to find the number of the movie, try this:

```
for i, film in enumerate(films):
     print('{0:3} {1:30} {2:5}'.format(i, film.title, film.time))

while True:
    try:
        film = films[int(input("Please select from our listings :"))]
    except (ValueError, IndexError), e:
        # input is not an integer between 0 and len(films)
        continue

    # now we have a valid film from the list
    print("You have selected film: ",film.title)
    # ...
```

Comment: how do I define valueError

Comment: ValueError is a built-in exception type, so you shouldn't need to define it. Can you provide a link to your full code via Pastebin or something similar? Also, can you confirm which version of Python is being used please. :)

Comment: I am using Python 3.2.3 here is the link to my Pastebin http://pastebin.com/b8P1JfU4 user name: Kezborn

Comment: I figured the problem with valueError is case sensitivity, its fixed now. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the film id as a key, it might be worth using a dictionary to store your films instead of a list. That way you can just use "in" to check if your film id keys exists in the dictionary without having to worry about out of bounds exceptions.

```
class Film(object):
    def __init__(self, title, time):
        self.title = title
        self.time = time

films = {}
films[29] = Film("End of Days", "20:00")
films[30] = Film("Gremlins", "19:30")
films[31] = Film("The Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn part 2", "20:30")

for k,v in films.iteritems():
    print (k, v.title, v.time)

while True:
    i = int(input("Please select from our listings:"))
    if i in films:
        print ("You have selected film: ", films[i].title)
        # select seat here
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: `for k,v in films.iteritems():` probably won't return the list in that order…

Comment: Agh. Good point. Would an OrderedDict work better in this instance?